# How to pass mongdb field to dynamic form element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Working on a web app. I have a route/view which populates bootstrap cards based on data from an API call to a URL. That data populates fine using a forEach loop and I use EJS to set the card elements such as a paragraph to the appropriate data from the API call. However, I have one element on the cards that is not included in the API call but I have the data in a local mongodb (using mongoose in this app). My skill level is very beginner so I'm not quite sure how to do this next part. I have looked thoroughly for an answer. I want to get the

element on the card to show the corresponding field from the db using an ID (which is dynamic based on the API call) to identify the correct data to use from the document. This app will show information on toll roads in each state. The API call returns all the toll roads for a state based on the user selecting a state. The bootstrap cards populate some basic information from the API call about the toll roads. But I have a toll description in the db which is not included. The bootstrap card will dynamically get a tollid which the db also has. I just need to figure out how to get the locdesc from the db based on the corresponding tollid on the card. I hope that makes sense. Code below....

I am able to do a find() and get the data from the db in my route so I feel like I'm almost there.

-------------------ROUTE-----------------------------------------------------

```
app.get("/results", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
var state = req.query.state

    Locationdesc.find({ state: state }, function(err, locdesc){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {


request("https://apiurlgoeshere" + state + "apiurlgoeshere", function(error, response, body){
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(body)
            res.render("results", {data:parsedData, locdesc:locdesc})

        }
    })
    }
    })
```

})

-----------------END ROUTE----------------------------

----------------VIEW------------------------------

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

 <div class="container">
     <header class="jumbotron mb-5">
         <div class="container text-center">
             <h1>Select a Toll to View Additional Information and Do Something with Notifications and Alerts</h1>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/search">Back To Search</a>
             </p>
     </div>
 </header>
```

```
    <div class="album py-">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
               <% data["features"].forEach(function(toll){ %>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 card-group">
              <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">

 <p class="card-text">Toll ID - <%= toll["attributes"]["tollid"] %></p>
 <p class="card-text">Cost- <%= toll["attributes"]["cost"] %></p>
 <p class="card-text">Location - <%= toll["attributes"]["location"] %></p>
 <p class="card-text">Location Description - ??????????????????????? </p>
 <p class="card-text hide">State - <%= gauge["attributes"]["state"] %></p>

                         </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

--------------------------------END VIEW----------------------------------

--------------------------------DB SCHEMA---------------------

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var locSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    locdesc: String,
    tollid: String,
    state: String
})

var Locationdesc = mongoose.model("Locationdesc", locSchema)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Locationdesc', locSchema);
```

Comment: Where is your location description stored ?

Comment: location description is stored in a mongodb. the schema above is the schema for the location description (Locationdesc) collection. It includes the state, location description, and toll id. The toll id is what the card will have that will tell me what location description to return. The view will have several cards on it so I will need to use the tollid from each card to return the locdesc for that particular card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to `locdesc`, what's wrong with this :

```
<div>
  <% data["features"].forEach(function(toll){ %>
    <p class="card-text">Toll ID - <%= toll["attributes"]["tollid"] %></p>
    <p class="card-text">Cost- <%= toll["attributes"]["cost"] %></p>
    <p class="card-text">Location - <%= toll["attributes"]["location"] %></p>
    <% if(locdesc.filter(location => location.tollid == toll["attributes"]["tollid"])[0]['locdesc']) { %>
      <p class="card-text">Location Description <%= locdesc.filter(location => location.tollid == toll.tollid)[0]['locdesc'] %>
    <% } %>
    <p class="card-text hide">State  <%= toll.state %></p>
  <% }) %>
</div>
```

Using `filter` would do the trick.

Comment: So I did try that earlier, but I didn't think it would work because...In the route and in the find() I am returning attributes for all the toll locations in a particular state. So, locdesc.locdesc is not specific enough. Each toll location has it's own card and the cards populate for all toll locations in the state. The locdesc does have the tollid field which would be the same in the card and in the db. I hope that makes sense. I think I need a (pseudo code follows): locdesc.locdesc where tollid on card equals tollid in db...

Comment: You could use `filter`, then select the first item in the returned array .

Comment: My lack of knowledge here is embarrassing. I'm not sure how to do that but will research it and get back...soon, I hope!

Comment: This is definitely the right track. Made great progress. I couldn't get it work using arrow notation so I fiddled around with it using the function() notation. So, I am getting the the full document returned from the db. It's only 3 fields (state, tollid, and locdesc). The code: <%= toll["attributes"]["tollid"] %> I am using for the other elements refers to the API URL JSON, not the db. Heres is my code currently: <p class="card-text">Location Description - <%= locdesc.filter(function(locdesc) {return locdesc.tollid == toll["attributes"]["tolllid"]}) %> </p>....

Comment: The document IS going to the correct card so it matches the toll information pulled in from the url api.

Comment: Don't forget to check if locdesc is defined as shown in the answer.

Comment: So I think the issue that I'm maybe using nested arrays...Each array has {state, locdesc, tollid} in it. I am able to return that whole array in the respective card but all I need/want is the locdesc when tollid matches tollid from the api data. I might have to post a new question but I'm going to mark this one answered since your answer got me to where at least I can return something. Thanks so much and more to come...